# Checkboxes don't submit if unchecked, so how can I default them to true?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a form with a checkbox that's used to filter some search results.

The form action is `GET` so that the users can navigate back to the search results without having to OK the post data request message.

I want one of the checkboxes to default to true. This in itself is not a problem of course, it's simple HTML. However, it's the PHP that powers it that I'm struggling to figure out.

When the user visits the page for the first time, there won't be any `GET` variables set, meaning thisCheckbox would be unset and all the relevant checks would evaluate to false. Meaning I can't do:

```
#this returns a false negative
if (isset($_GET['thisCheckbox'])) echo 'checked="checked"';
```

If the user explicity ticks the checkbox and submits, then it's fine, because `$_GET['thisCheckbox']` will be true.

Is there a way of getting round this (without using radio buttons)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if it is set, and if it is not, check for other variables that are indicative of a request having taken place.

Comment: There might not be any - so perhaps the solution is to add a hidden input to the form (isSubmitted)? If (isSubmitted && thisCheckbox...) etc.

Comment: That would be a sollution, yes. But if you have a text field or anything else of the kind; that'll do just fine, as they are always successful.

Comment: That should probably be `$this->slap($this);` instead :P

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn I'm currently `static`!

Comment: If the get is performed by a form submit (which I suppose), the value of the submit button is sent as a request parameter as well.  So you can check if you're coming from a request by checking that paramter.  Which is probably why that is the behavior in the first place, so I suggest you use that.

Answer (score 2):

Not very nice, but what about introducing a hidden field `$_GET['filterApplied']`. If the user submits the form, this field is set. Than you can do it like

```
if (!isset($_GET['filterApplied'] || isset($_GET['thisCheckbox'])) echo 'checked="checked"';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery, do :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#thisCheckbox").attr("checked",true);
});
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: OP says, "I want one of the checkboxes to default to true. This in itself is not a problem of course, it's simple HTML." So actually showing the checkbox to be checked is not a problem here. OP is looking for a way to set a server-side script variable which HTML and JS can't control.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `$_GET` for anything else, you can also do

```
if( empty( $_GET ) || isset( $_GET['thisCheckbox'] ) ) {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly approach, but it works. Add a hidden input field with the same name above your checkbox.

```
<input type="hidden" name="thisCheckbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="thisCheckbox" value="1">
```